# Bitcoin-qt constructing a transaction and choosing the index of the ins and outs

Tags: bitcoin-core, utxo, bitcoin-qt-setup, coin-selection, txindex

While using Bitcoin-qt I understand there is the "Coin Selection" option.

Is there also a way to choose the ordering index of the utxo's for the inputs or outputs?

I'm trying to avoid the cli if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Bitcoin Core will randomize the order of inputs and outputs when constructing a transaction. I think that this is also the case when you use coin control to manually pick your inputs. As far as I’m aware, you will need to either create your own PSBT or use `sendrawtransaction` to determine the order of the inputs and outputs.

Comment: i was afraid of this.. but thanks for the quick answer.